# Is it possible to have a shortcut of two keys that don't involve Alt or Ctrl or Shift?

Tags: c++, winapi

I haven't encountered any application so far that has a shortcut combination such as "A+S", is this because it's not possible to create such a shortcut, or simply because "Alt/Ctrl/Shift+someKey" is the standard way to do it?

Comment: I don't know what your API allows, but keyboards can't handle all arbitrary combinations of keys, since the signals from the keys are multiplexed (if I understand it correctly). A+S seems to work on my keyboard, but I don't know whether there are any key combinations that work reliably on all keyboards, other than [any modifier keys] + [one non-modifier key].

Comment: Just about any keyboard can handle any two key combination. For keyboards that use a wire matrix without any diodes, then some three key combinations (letters and numbers) will appear to be four key combinations, so they usually wait for a key release to get back to two or less keys pressed (called rollover handling). Alt, Ctrl, and Shift are usually handled separately on these keyboard, so two keys + Alt and/or Ctrl and/or Shift will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to create the shortcut combinations like that, but think while typing if the user presses A+S or something like A+C or T+O etc.. user types such combinations various times while using applications or typing words fastly if your shortcut gets triggered each time then instead of giving easiness you are annoying the user.

Ctrl, and Shift button are special keys which actually changes the primary meaning of other keys and it is a standard way of creating shortcuts.